# Azure Web Roles e Worker Roles

Tags: microsoft-azure

O que é o Azure Web Role e Worker Role? Quais as diferenças entre eles e em quais cenários podemos utilizar cada um?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A principal diferença entre os dois é que Web Role é executado com o suporte do IIS, enquanto uma Worker Role não.

Exemplificando, um WebRole é uma aplicação web que irá realizar uma operação que não possui retornos, e não precisam ter, necessariamente, baixa latência. Possui um *endpoint* para ser disparado via HTTP, mas tem-se a preocupação com *timeout* do IIS.

O mesmo com Worker Role, mas esse é como uma aplicação de Console, não necessita do IIS para ser executado, consequentemente não há um *endpoint* para ele e nem preocupação com *timeout*.